# Useful ReadLn in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, functional-programming

Is there in Haskell a built-in function like ReadLn in Pascal?

I want smth like this:

```
λ> pascalReadLn :: IO (Int, Int, Int, Int)
1 2
3
4
(1,2,3,4)
λ> pascalReadLn :: IO (Int, Int, Int, Int)
1 2 3 4
(1,2,3,4)
λ> pascalReadLn :: IO (Int, Int, Int, Int)
1
2
3
4
(1,2,3,4)
...
etc.
```

Comment: It is too flexible. I do not believe this kind of read function is possible in Haskell.

Comment: It certainly is possible, though not with the proposed type.

Comment: Isn't it simply readIO or a sequence of readIO followed by getLine?

Comment: N.B.: In the above, I really meant "not with the proposed type, assuming you want to reuse some or all of the implementation for tuples of different sizes".

Answer (score 7):

You can sort of hack this together using [`ReadArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ReadArgs)

```
import ReadArgs

pascalReadLn :: ArgumentTuple a => IO a
pascalReadLn = pascalReadLn' ""
  where pascalReadLn' lines = do
          line <- getLine
          let lines' = lines ++ line
          -- see if we've read enough to successfully parse the desired tuple
          case parseArgsFrom (words lines') of
            Nothing -> pascalReadLn' (lines' ++ "\n")
            Just a  -> return a
```

And it works as desired for valid input

```
λ pascalReadLn :: IO (Int, Int, Int, Int)
1 2
3
4
(1,2,3,4)
λ pascalReadLn :: IO (Int, Int, Int, Int)
1 2 3 4
(1,2,3,4)
λ pascalReadLn :: IO (Int, Int, Int, Int)
1
2
3
4
(1,2,3,4)
```

It's not perfect, however, as it can't differentiate between an incomplete parse and an impossible parse:

```
λ pascalReadLn :: IO (Int, Int, Int, Int)
foo bar
1
2
3
4
... will go forever
```

A custom implementation (along the same lines as `ArgumentTuple`) could solve this by differentiating between the two failure cases, with something like:

```
 data ParseResult a = Success a | Incomplete (String -> ParseResult a) | Impossible

 class LineTuple a where
   parseLine :: String -> ParseResult a
```

Comment: This will work fine until you try to input a sixteen or more elements tuple. But I guess that is too crazy :-)

Comment: I figured if [`Eq` didn't have an instance for 16 element tuples](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq), I didn't have to either. Plus there's `:&` for arbitrary length tuples.